# Swift in Xcode 6: How to use geocoding properly with Google Maps?

Tags: xcode, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm new to swift. I am trying to create a call to Google's API to convert any inputted addresses to a long, lat location on google maps, using their sdk.

I thought it'd be easier to start by following a tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/, then dissecting it. But I cannot seem to get it this particular line working. It will come out with a "error-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0" on the dicitonary line. I read other sample work on reverse geocoding that are to date, and they look very similar, but none are working. What am I doing wrong?

```
let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = 
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: 
NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! 
Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
```

Full function below:

```
func geocodeAddress(address: String!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {
    if let lookupAddress = address {
        var geocodeURLString = baseURLGeocode + "address=" + lookupAddress
        geocodeURLString = geocodeURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let geocodeURL = NSURL(string: geocodeURLString)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let geocodingResultsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: geocodeURL!)


            var error: NSError?
            let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
           // let dictionary: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! Dictionary


            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
                completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
            }
            else {
                // Get the response status.
                let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

                if status == "OK" {
                    let allResults = dictionary["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
                    self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

                    // Keep the most important values.
                    self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as! String
                    let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                    self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
                    self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

                    completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: "No valid address.", success: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2, this can be used:

First, declare your variable as an empty dictionary outside of the do-catch block and do the assignment in the block, like below

```
            do {
                dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
            } catch {
                //something
            }
```